# Reading a XML document in VB.net from the internet

Tags: xml, vb.net

Take a example..

```
Private Sub Button2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://example.com/page.xml")

    End Sub
```

Above code displays the XML content in webbrowser1 control on Button_Click.
But I dont want display in webbrowser. I want read the content from xml document to use elsewhere.

I just need to know how to get this XML file to use elsewhere (other than webbrowser control) from a web address...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: That depends on what you want to use it for, and what the content is. Be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `XmlDocument.Load` method can be given either a local file name or a web address URL, for instance:

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.Load("http://example.com/page.xml")
```

The `Load` method of the `XDocument` and `XElement` classes also work the same way.

If you want to get the XML document as a string, so you can parse it through some other means, such as the `XmlSerializer`, you can use the `HttpWebRequest` class. See this page for an example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx